# Click mouse button to wake the mouse without sending the click to the PC?

Tags: mouse, sleep

My new wireless mouse sleeps after a few minutes to save power. Waking it requires clicking a button. The problem is the mouse then sends the click to my PC. If my mouse happens to be over a button, the button gets clicked. If it's over another window, the computer switches windows.

I often can't locate the mouse cursor without moving the mouse, and the mouse doesn't move when it's sleeping, so it's difficult to avoid clicking random things. Using the right or middle mouse buttons is less problematic, but still does stuff I don't want, switching windows or entering panning mode.

I'd prefer it if a click that wakes the mouse wasn't sent on to the PC. Do any wireless mice work that way? Maybe the cheap one I got is just poorly designed.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. [Here](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln301788/dell-km714-wireless-mouse-sleep-power-behavior?lang=en) is an example of a wireless mouse that can be woken up in a number of ways. It's not quite the same as not sending the click on to the PC, but it would allow you to avoid the problem by moving the mouse, which is much, much less likely to cause unwanted side-effects than clicking is. What is the make/model of your mouse?

Comment: I’ve honestly never had a wireless mouse that didn’t wake up by simply moving it. And I’ve used a lot of them.

Comment: Amazon calls it a "Wireless Mouse, WISFOX 2.4G Full Size Computer Mouse Wireless Ergonomic Mouse 6 Buttons Laptop Mouse USB Mouse with Nano Receiver 5-Level DPI Adjustable Cordless Wireless Mice for Windows(Black)" by WISFOX. So I guess this $9 mouse just has a design flaw. It wakes only by button presses, and neither moving the mouse nor rolling the wheel will wake it. I'd be perfectly happy if I could wiggle the mouse to wake it, and it sounds like that works on some (maybe most?) wireless mice. Guess I'll be getting a different mouse. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

This always was driving me crazy!  I finally figured out that if you give it a light tap, almost lifting the mouse off the desk, quickly, it will wake... without sending a click signal to the computer. Give it a try!